# Confusion with npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to figure out how the https://github.com/fastify/fastify-example-twitter/blob/master/package.json works.

Specifically, it has a script entry as: `"start": "fastify index.js"`.

However, there is no requirement to install `fastify` globally. Nonetheless, `npm start` is working fine. It does start `fastify`, while doing it from the shell results in: `-bash: fastify: command not found`

What is happening when `npm start` is invoked? Why I cannot run this from the command line, while `npm` runs this script command just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fastify` is listed as a dependency, and as such can be ran as an npm script. The same goes for `mocha`, `standard`, and `snazzy`. None of them need to be globally installed, but are ran via their npm scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If your dependency appears in an npm script command, the executable is added to your path.

From the [`npm scripts` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path):

> If you depend on modules that define executable scripts, like test
>   suites, then those executables will be added to the PATH for executing
>   the scripts. So, if your package.json has this:
>
> ```
> { 
>     "name" : "foo" , 
>     "dependencies" : { 
>       "bar" : "0.1.x" 
>     } , 
>     "scripts": {
>       "start" : "bar ./test" 
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> then you could run npm start to execute the bar script, which is
>   exported into the node_modules/.bin directory on npm install.